# How can I make my text wrap around my image?

Tags: html, css

In my website, I have a page like this:

```html
<div style="float:left; width: 75%;  padding:15px 0px 0px 0px;">
    <h1>HEADING</h1>
    <h3>TEXT TEXT TEXT</h3>
    <p>TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT<p>
    <p>TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT<p> 
    <p>TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT<p>
    <p>TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT<p>
    </div>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x300/000/fff" style="float:right; width:25%; min-width:200px;>
```

As you can see,**I've tried floating my image right and my text left** as all the other suggested questions prompted, but that doesn't seem to make it wrap around.
Also, I want to make it appear like this on mobile:

```
HEADING
TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
etc...
IMAGE
```

What else can I do to achieve this?

**NOTE:** I am aware how much you guys hate inline css lmao. It's just that I'm in such a situation that I must do so. It's hard to explain. :/

EDIT: 
I used the code provided in the answers:

```
<div style="width: 75%;padding:15px 0px 0px 0px;">
<h1>HEADING</h1>
<h3>TEXT TEXT TEXT</h3>
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x300/000/fff" style="float:right;    width:25%; min-width:200px;" />
 <p>TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
 </p>
 <p>TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
  </p>
  <p>TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
 </p>
 <p>TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
 </p>
</div>
```

This works fine on the PC view, but viewing it on mobile is a whole different story... the text doesn't wrap around the image at all... how can I fix that?

Answer (score 2):

Put your image at the top most point where you want text to wrap it.

It also mus be in its container

another note you where missing `" />` from your `img`

you also didn't end your `<p>` tags correctly `</p>`

```html
<div style="width: 75%;padding:15px 0px 0px 0px;">
  <h1>HEADING</h1>
  <h3>TEXT TEXT TEXT</h3>
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x300/000/fff" style="float:right; width:25%; min-width:200px;" />
  <p>TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
  </p>
  <p>TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
  </p>
  <p>TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
  </p>
  <p>TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
  </p>
</div>
```

**update on request**

Here is how you get your image to sit at the bottom of your text even although its at the top when in mobile

```css
div {
  width: 75%;
  padding: 15px 0px 0px 0px;
  display: table;
}
img {
  width: 25%;
  min-width: 200px;
  display: table-footer-group;
}
p,
h1,
h3 {
  display: table-caption;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>HEADING</h1>
  <h3>TEXT TEXT TEXT</h3>
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x300/000/fff" />
  <p>TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
  </p>
  <p>TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
  </p>
  <p>TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
  </p>
  <p>TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: It works nice... only when I'm viewing it on PC. Viewing it in mobile is a whole different story, the text doesn't wrap around the image. How can I fix that?

Comment: But this way, image will come before text in mobile view. But as per format mentioned in question, text should come before image in mobile view ?

Comment: thats just how the cookie crumbles my friend ill update my answer to show you a way to change the location of the image

Comment: @DCdaz , I appreciate your super-quick response, but that's not exactly what I want... I want the text to wrap around the image. It's doing so on PC, but not on mobile...

Comment: there's not enough room matey. you should really separate you'r image from text after a certain point otherwise it becomes illegible or your image becomes to small to comprehend.

Answer (score 0):

Put your image at first and also you mess close bracket `/` in your image tag.

```
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x300/000/fff" style="float:right; 
width:25%; min-width:200px;" />
```